# WHILE Loop Condition Does Not Validate Input

Tags: java, exception, netbeans, while-loop, conditional-statements

I have a `WHILE`loop which checks for marks for a particular student. However, it does not loop if the value is invalid (input less than 0 and more than 100):

```
int marks= -1;

System.out.print("Student Marks (/100): ");
                while (((marks< 0) || (marks> 100))) {
                    try {
                        marks = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
                        break;
                    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { 
                        System.err.println("Error: Invalid Mark(s)");
                        System.out.print("Student Marks (/100): ");
                    }
                }
```

It does catches exception if characters other than numbers are entered.

But it does not loop again if value if less than 0 or more than 100.

I have tried making many changes to it but to no result.

Any help given is appreciated!

Comment: Your loop, as is, loops ONLY if the mark is invalid.

Comment: Since you didn't parse  marks to integer before - ` while (((marks< 0) || (marks>  100)))` - this line I am not sure whether you can check against with the 0 and 100. I am not sure just want to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should remove the `break` statement, since it breaks you out of the loop regardless of what value of `marks` was input.

Comment: Would it loop then? Because marks is always set to -1, it's neither incrementing nor decrementing.

Comment: @Apurva It would loop as long as `(((marks< 0) || (marks> 100)))` if you remove the break statement. Otherwise it will break after the first iteration in which `Integer.parseInt` doesn't throw a NumberFormatException. I would also add a check that `sc.nextLine()` doesn't return null (before calling parseInt), in which case you should break from the loop, since no more input is available.

Comment: Thank you @Eran. Removing the `break`statement resumes the loop

Answer (score 1):

You may check the `marks` inside the `while` loop with an `if` condition  and here you may use `break` -

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TakeInput{ 

    public static void main(String args[]){

        int marks= -1;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Student Marks (/100): ");
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            try {
                marks = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
                if(marks<0 || marks>100){
                    break;
                }
                //do something
                // with the marks

                //take new marks
                System.out.print("Student Marks (/100): ");
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { 
                System.err.println("Error: Invalid Mark(s)");
                System.out.print("Student Marks (/100): ");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Now as long as you enter anything except a number n when `n<0 || n>100` will continue the loop. Any `NumberFormatExeption` take you to the `catch` block.

If you enter 34 then it goes to the while block and prompt for a next number.
Then if you enter 56 then it dose the same thing.
When you enter any `String` rather than a number than it goes to the catch `block`
This process continues until you enter a invalid number (n>100 || n<100). Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> also exit you from the loop.

Hope it will help you.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Always use continue instead of break if you want to keep the loop running.